# Is it possible to use 'ALG_HMAC_SHA1' method from 'Signature' class in javacard framework 2.2.1 version?

Tags: sha1, hmac, javacard, one-time-password, hmacsha1

I want to use ALG_HMAC_SHA1 method from javacard.security.Signature class. But my javacard framework version is 2.2.1 so Signature class does not include this method for this version. 
it includes this method after 2.2.2. Is it possible to use this method without upgrading framework version?

Answer (score 4):

You could always just use the value that you find in the 2.2.2 framework for the constant `ALG_HMAC_SHA1` (= `(byte)24`) and pass it to the `Signature.getInstance()` method. So using the **value** is not a problem. However, the smartcard hardware on which you want to run your applet needs to support this algorithm in order for you to be able to use.

So if your smartcard hardware supports JC 2.2.1, calling the `getInstance()` method with the value of `ALG_HMAC_SHA1` will typically cause a `CryptoException` with reason (`CryptoException.NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM`) indicating that the algorithm is not supported and JC 2.2.1 does not support any HMAC algorithms). Using the public constant directly will likely result in upload or installation failure.

Just to be clear here, I'm not suggesting that compiling for a different framework version might suddenly solve your problem. I'm rather suggesting that you can **not** simply upgrade the functionality that is available on your card.

Comment: How do I know if my hardware supports it? I'm using USim Card R6.

Comment: As I wrote above in my answer: call the `Signature.getInstance()` method with `(byte)24` as algorithm parameter. If it returns a `Signature` object, your card supports it; if it returns `null`, your card does not support it (that's what I expect).

Comment: It returns 'null'. Is the **block size** of `SHA1`, the reason for not supporting?

Comment: The reason why it's not supported by your card is simply because your card is based on JC 2.2.1 and that specification does not include that algorithm.

Comment: Downvoted. For one, you should always compile for the correct version as the Java Card standard does not use the normal late binding. Furthermore, hoping that Signature suddenly handles another algorithm is not likely. Extensions are normally using a separate API e.g. `my.company.SignatureX.getInstance()`, using the one defined by Oracle will get you in trouble. Finally a well behaved applet should not return null but a `CryptoException` with `CryptoException.NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM`. If it returns `null` then the card behavior is wrong.

Comment: @owlstead You are right, the `getInstance()` method should throw a `NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM` exception. Thank's for pointing that out. With regard to your second comment. That was not the point of my answer. Instead, I wanted to make clear to the OP that simply using a value (algorithm parameter) from a different JC framework version won't just magically make that algorithm available on his card.

Comment: OK, that's fair. Made it a bit more clear and voted up instead.

Answer (score 3):

The HMAC algorithm is not a big deal. As long as your card supports SHA-1 you can simply implement the algorithm on your own.
See [RFC2104](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104) for details and [RFC2202](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2202) for test vectors.

BTW: You can not "upgrade the framework version" of a JavaCard - the Card OS and the JavaCard framework is usually not changeable (stored in ROM). You can only buy a different card...